# 1С Bitrix. Как увеличить глубину вложенности разделов при импорте товаров? Тариф - Малый бизнес

Tags: php, битрикс

В настройках модуля "Информационные блоки" параметр "**Максимальный уровень глубины вложенности разделов для CSV-экспорта/импорта**" установлен "**10**". Но при настройке профиля импорта возможность выбрать только **3** уровня разделов.
Как увеличить глубину вложенности для импорта?

Сам фронтенд, но чуток разбираюсь в php и бэкенде Битрикса, совсем немного.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пока решил костылем жестко задав в скрипте профиля переменной $NUM_CATALOG_LEVELS нужное значение.

Answer (score 0):

Решил.
В настройках модуля **Торговый каталог** по вкладке "Импорт/Экспорт" выставляется требуемая максимальная глубина вложенности. Там же выставляется перечень полей, доступных для экспорта и импорта.